# API endpoint for data from Microsoft Exchange Online Protection?

Tags: python, rest, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

I am working on a project where I have been using Python to make API calls to our organization's various technologies to get data, which I then push to Power BI to track metrics over time relating to IT Security.

My boss wants to see info added from Exchange Online Protection such as malware detected in emails, spam blocks etc., essentially replicating some of the email and collaboration reports you'd see in M365 defender > reports > email and collaboration (security.microsoft.com/emailandcollabreport).

I have tried the Defender API and MS Graph API, read through a ton of documentation, and can't seem to find anywhere to pull this info from. Has anyone done something similar, or know where this data can be pulled from?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this, this is the solution I ended up using (hacky as it may be);

The only way to extract the pertinent info seems to be through PowerShell, you need the modules ExchangeOnlineManagement and PSWSMan so those will need to be installed.

You need to add an app to your Azure instance with global reader role minimum (or something custom) and generate and upload self-signed certificates to the app.

I then ran the following lines as a ps1 script:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -CertificateFilePath "<PATH>" -AppID "<APPID>" -Organization "<ORG>.onmicrosoft.com" -CertificatePassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -String '<PASSWORD>' -AsPlainText -Force)
$dte = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
Get-MailflowStatusReport -StartDate $dte -EndDate (Get-Date)
Disconnect-ExchangeOnline
```

I used python to call the powershell script, then extract the info I needed from the output and push it to PowerBI.

I'm sure there is a more secure and efficient way to do this but I was able to accomplish the task this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Microsoft Graph Security API using which you can get the alerts, information protection, secure score using that. Also you can refer the [alerts section in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/security-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0#alerts) which talks about the list of supported providers at this point using the Microsoft Graph security api.